# How to use scss @import rule on odoo?

Tags: css, sass, odoo, odoo-14

I am trying to use @import rule on my styles so that I can manage them in a more efficient way but unfortunately it is not working. I am getting the error below. The thing is that I see in many odoo themes that people use it. So, what is missing then? I would appreciate, if you know the solution.

```
Style error

The style compilation failed, see the error below. Your recent actions may be the cause, please try reverting the changes you made.

Local import './main' is forbidden for security reasons. Please remove all @import {your_file} imports in your custom files. In Odoo you have to import all files in the assets, and not through the @import statement.
```